# Best way to mock method while testing golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, interface

```
package main

import "fmt"

type I1 interface {
    A() string
    B() string
}

type S1 struct {
    name string
    i    I1
}

func NewS1(name string) *S1 {
    s := &S1{
        name: name,
    }
    s.i = s
    return s
}
func (s *S1) A() string {
    // This is the method I want to override in my tests
    return "A() was called"
}
func (s *S1) B() string {
    return s.i.A()
}

func main() {
    s1 := NewS1("no matter")
    fmt.Println(s1.B())
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "testing"
)

type S1Mock struct {
    *S1
}

func (*S1Mock) A() string {
    return "A() from mock was called!"
}

func TestS1_B(t *testing.T) {
    s1mock := S1Mock{NewS1("lol")}
    s1mock.i = &s1mock
    if s1mock.B() != "A() from mock was called!" {
        log.Fatal("error")
    }
}
```

I'm experimenting with Go interfaces and embedding.
The following code does exactly what I want it to do, which is to mock the `B()` method during tests. But in my solution, I'm forced to keep an interface embedded in my `S1` struct, which seems awkward (notice the `s.i = s` in the `NewS1` method).
Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve this?

Why does the following not work? The `A()` method from the `S1Mock` is never invoked.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type I1 interface {
    A() string
    B() string
}

type S1 struct {
    name string
}

func NewS1(name string) *S1 {
    s := &S1{
        name: name,
    }
    return s
}
func (s *S1) A() string {
    // Doing things this is the method I want to override
    return "A() was called"
}
func (s *S1) B() string {
    return s.A()
}

func main() {
    s1 := NewS1("no matter")
    fmt.Println(s1.B())
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "testing"
)

type S1Mock struct {
    *S1
}

func (*S1Mock) A() string {

    return "A() from mock was called!"
}

func TestS1_B(t *testing.T) {
    s1mock := S1Mock{NewS1("lol")}
    if s1mock.B() != "A() from mock was called!" {
        log.Fatalf("Wanted %s got %s", "A() from mock was called!", s1mock.B())
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to keep an embedded interface. The type *S1 implements I1.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I edited the question and added an example implementing what I think you are trying to say, but I don't think I'm getting it right, the A() method from the mock is not invoked.

Comment: You are trying to implement late binding and override a method. That is not going to work. You can use a function variable in S1 and change it during test.

Comment: The best way is not to mock at all.